# Avoiding PHP workaround for double GROUP BY sql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to make a SQL query of counted grouped results. The only way I was able to do it was with the help of PHP. But I am sure that it is possible to do it in one SQL statement.

The table's structure is the following:
`id`, `user_hash`, `timestamp`

And my little PHP workaround looks like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT count(id) AS \'total clicks\' FROM stats WHERE timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL '.$num_days.' DAY) GROUP BY user_hash ORDER BY count(id) DESC';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$count = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (isset($count[$row['total clicks']])) {
        $count[$row['total clicks']]++;
    } else {
        $count[$row['total clicks']] = 1;
    }
}

foreach ($count as $k => $v) {
    echo $v." users clicked ".$k." times\n";
}
```

I am probably going to kick myself how easy it is, but I just can't seem to get to an all-in-one SQL solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
$sql = 'SELECT
    A.`user_times_clicked`,
    COUNT(A.user_hash) AS `user_count`
FROM(
    SELECT 
        count(id) AS `user_times_clicked`,
        user_hash   
    FROM 
        stats 
    WHERE 
        timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL '.$num_days.' DAY) 
    GROUP BY 
        user_hash 
    ) AS A
GROUP BY    
    A.`user_times_clicked`
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(A.user_hash) DESC'
```

I hope it helps.